# django-cms "You do not have permission to add a plugin" as superuser

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I installed django-cms 3.0.6 (the latest version as of today) on top of an existing Django 1.7 / Python 2.7 project with sqlite3 as the db.

Having created a simple template and placeholder, I get an error when trying to add a plugin using the front end content editor (for example the "Generic / Picture" plugin). Here's my template file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}      
{% load cms_tags %}            


{% block content %}            
    {% placeholder template1_content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Even though I am logged in as superuser a pop-up appears saying "You do not have permissions to add a plugin" when I attempt to add a plugin.

Aside from not being able to add plugins, everything else about the django-cms interface seems to be running fine - I can view the admin, create pages, toggle between live and draft, etc.

I have looked inside the django-cms code and it appears the error is originating from a publisher_is_draft check inside the class cms.admin.pageadmin.PageAdmin:

```
def has_add_plugin_permissions(self, request, placeholder, plugin_type):
    ...
    ...                       
    if page and not page.publisher_is_draft:                                 
        return False                                                         
    return True
```

Basically, it appears django-cms does not think the page is in draft mode, even though I have entered 'draft mode' according to the front end (ie: toggled the 'live' mode icon to 'draft'). The fact that the other checks in the above function pass confirms that the error is not a user permission issue (indeed, as I mentioned above, the error happens as superuser) but something about the page state.

Is this just an issue with integration of django-cms 3.0.6 with Django 1.7, or am I missing something obvious? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you staff too? (is_staff)

Comment: laffuste: Yes, I am active, staff and superuser.

Comment: I've just come across a similar situation which *isn't* related to any replication of middleware. In my case, I was using an apphooked model. This model extended a CMS page which itself contained a placeholder. This placeholder would then appeared to me within a template within my app but, since it was connected to the CMS page and not the app, I had no permissions to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I narrowed down the problem to my settings.py file. In MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES I originally had a duplicate entry for 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' (see the first and last lines):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
)
```

The correct config is:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)
```

After deleting this duplicate line, restarting the server and logging out  / in (presumably to refresh the session), the problem went away. On the other hand after restoring the duplicate line, restarting the server and logging out / in, the problem returned.

Unfortunately, I do not understand *why* the duplicate line causes a problem - however at this stage, I am fine with delaying such an understanding for another time.

Given that duplicate lines seem to cause problems (and that such problems can be rather time consuming to debug), it would be nice if Django threw an error in the presence of such misconfigurations.

Comment: Because I don't understand why the duplicate line is causing a problem, I'm going to wait on accepting my own answer for a few days in the chance that someone might provide some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the permission issue if I've tried to add or adjust a plugin or template on a page that's an instance of an app.

For instance, if you try to change something from the frontend on a blog, you won't have the permission to do so if you're on a blog entry -- you have to be on the blog's parent page to make any changes, no matter what your status is.

It has something to do with the fact that multiple pages running under an app *look* like they're separate pages, but under the hood they're all variations of the same page, and just given dummy URLs.

I suppose a workaround -- in the case of a blog app -- to having something like a gallery only appear on specific children of the parent page would be to add the plugin to the parent page, where it'll be  optional on all children pages, but you simply ignore it 99% of the time, and it won't affect the pages that you don't want it on.